# How to overload a JavaScript function? (changing Slickgrid's editor)

Tags: javascript, slickgrid, overloading

I'm using Slickgrid and I would like to change behavior of editor. Instead of copy&paste I tried to overload one of functions but it doesn't work. I cannot read loadValue function.

loadValue is defined as (some code omitted)

```
    IntegerCellEditor : function(args) {
        this.loadValue = function(item) {
            defaultValue = item[args.column.field];
            $input.val(defaultValue);
            $input[0].defaultValue = defaultValue;
            $input.select();
        };
    }
```

What I tried is:

```
    function tristateIntegerCellEditor(check_field) { 
        var f = IntegerCellEditor;
        var f_loadValue = f.loadValue;

        f.loadValue = function(item) {
            f_loadValue(item);

            if (check_field) {
                if (!item[check_field]) {
                    $select.disable();
                }
            }
        };

        return f;
    }
```

Is there any way to substitute my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `f_loadValue.call(this, item);`

Otherwise the old `loadValue` get's called with it's context (`this`) as `window` (the default).

**Related:**

- [Adding hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789630/javascript-function-hooks/789654#789654)
- [_.wrap](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#wrap)

Comment: Problem is that result of f.loadValue is undefined, how to get function?